# My hands are cold in synagogue. May I put them in my pockets? May I wear gloves?

Tags: tefilla, clothing, synagogue

If my hands are cold when praying in synagogue:

1) may I put them in my pockets? Is it just disrespectful, as I was brought up to think, or are there more important issues?

2) may I wear gloves? (Any difference in whether the fingers are cut out or not?)

Comment: Why are your hands cold while you're praying in synagogue?

Comment: I have never heard that it's disrespectful to put your hands in your pockets. And I can't see any reason why wearing gloves in synagogue should be a problem - except that people may look at you funny.

Comment: How would you dress to meet a king in a cold room?

Comment: I'm not sure how having fingers exposed through the gloves would make a difference unless you're using a touchscreen device to Daven. Presumably, there should be traditional Siddurim to use, though.

Comment: @unforgettableid - Because the synagogue is cold? The A/C may be too high, the heat is too low, bad circulation to extremities, odd medication, moved to a new location, etc...

Comment: @eykanal: If we knew why the original poster's hands were cold, maybe we could advise him or her better.

Comment: Dear original poster:  Would you like a suggestion to help you keep your hands warm while looking more stylish?:  Perhaps you could wear a sweater or suit jacket with extra-long sleeves, and could keep your hands retracted except while turning pages.

Comment: My hands are cold because the synagogue is cold and I sit near a closed window which is nevertheless cold. I have ideas on how to warm hands; I was interested to learn if gloves were an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tzohar journal Page 433](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50926&st=&pgnum=433&hilite=) that it is improper to wear gloves during Tefila. (sources Bach, [Magen Avraham 91:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=286), Elya Rabba, [Pri Megadim 91:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40464&st=&pgnum=67).

Halichos Shlomo 2:18 in the name of Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach Zatzal and [Shaalos U'Tshuvos Neta Sorek 6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1322&st=&pgnum=20) say this is limited to dress gloves which are worn for Chashivus since it is haughty to wear them, however regular gloves worn for cold are permitted.

Comment: On which siman(im) are all those achronim found? Do they discuss if there is a difference when it is cold and wearing gloves wouldn't look haughty/like you are otherwise busy/like you couldn't bother to take them off?

Comment: Perhaps then the OP can wear gloves in Shul the whole time except Shmone Esrei. That might solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna Brurah in siman 92:12 writes that one should not wear hentslach which are gloves worn by travlers.However,the passuk he uses is about gaivah so the idea would extended to gaivadik gloves or acting in a gaivadik way.