# Putting hands in pockets during Prayer

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hands-fingers

I remember hearing that one should not pray with ones hands in their pockets because its considered haughty. Is there a source for this concept,or is it made up?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21731/my-hands-are-cold-in-synagogue-may-i-put-them-in-my-pockets-may-i-wear-gloves

Comment: No source, so not an asnwer but "Hands in Pockets during Davening Q: Is it permissible to put my hands in my pockets during davening? A: Certainly not.  You must stand as if you are before a king. " http://www.ateretmedia.org/shoot/SMS_048.pdf and "Based on the Gemara and poskim, it’s inappropriate to keep one’s hands in the pockets of their pants" http://www.torah2go.org/527-the-appropriate-position-for-ones-hands-during-davening/ General sources at the bottom http://www.halacha2go.com/blog/tx00527/

Comment: Would you stand before a mighty king with your hands in your pockets? Certainly not.

Comment: @ezra Why certainly not? I don't think it's such a big deal nowadays.

Comment: hands in the pockets is considered "haughty"? Hmm ... my parents and teachers told me that hands in the pockets makes one seem "shleppy" and "poor". I am pretty certain that SA says that one should pray slightly bent over and not straight.

Comment: Aloof is a better terminology than haughty.

Comment: @DanF - My parents always told me that putting hands in pockets makes you look like a punk.

Comment: @Danno What about "Kol yisroel b'nei melachim?" That would imply that our posture shouldn't be one of a subject to the king, but of a family member to the king, who might reasonably be more comfortable in the kings presence...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Can you source that expression. Even with that being true, doesn't that conflict with the fear  when standing before the king?

Comment: @DanF we also have an obligation to fear our parents too, it's not a contradiction at all! The concept gets invoked in lots of places, famously in the mishnah on shabbos regarding children wearing bells (like princes), and in bava metzia regarding ones obligations to employees and debtors. It's really all over shas...

Comment: I heard some men do not do it to stay away from touching their organ